# Find city radius

Tags: google-maps, maps

I am working on an app where I need to check if some points are within a city or X km outside of it, so I need to find the city's radius then add the X variable to it. I've been looking on Google Maps and OpenStreetMap and I could not find such info.
Is there any API that provides the city's average width? Or distance between the center and the edge?

Comment: I'm looking for a same thing, need to send notification citywise, so need to get the radius of a city and then will calculate if user's lat lng are within that radius or not, if yes then will send the notifications. Did you find anything, please share?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Latitude & Longitude of two given points, you can find the distance between those points.

So fetch the Location (Latitude & Longitude) for the centre of city and the point needed, using Google Maps API's and find out the distance implementing the logic.

Logic is described in below link :
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Post calculation of distance, you verify if it is in the required range based on X.

Comment: I know, but I need to find the radius of the city (distance from center to edge or from edge to edge crossing the middle), so I can increase it by X km. Only then I need to find if the point I'm checking has a distance from itself to center smaller than the city's edge to center.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and here is the best method I found so far,

Using the service [Geoapify](https://www.geoapify.com/)

you can find the placeid for a city using the [geocoding API](https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api/)

We can then create a location filter based on the place id as documented [here](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/docs/geocoding/forward-geocoding/#api)

we can also use that filter for autocomplete to allow only for places inside the city